# What is the create2 function's equivalent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, keccak

I imported this create library for the keccak encryptor:

https://blog.8bitzen.com/posts/18-03-2019-keccak-abi-encodepacked-with-javascript/

Now I made a js function:

```
    const pair = soliditySha3(
         '0xff',
         factory.address,
         soliditySha3(testAddresses[0], testAddresses[1]),
         soliditySha3(initCode)
        )
```

Where initCode is '0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f', which I took from the Uniswap website.  I am trying to test a local deployment of their code.

Is there an easier way?